# Creating IIS Instance over network using MSBuild

Tags: iis, msbuild, teamcity

Is there a way to have MSBuild create an instance of IIS on another remote machine?

I do the builds (which occur locally using TeamCity AFAIK), but would like the code to be pushed up to our testing server once the build is completed. I am using IIS 6.x (Windows XP dev and Windows 2k3 Server for testing).

Comment: With Eric's suggestion, I took a look at MSBuild Extension Pack. The key is setting the MachineName attribute in the IIS6Website tag. When you add that, you'll get the IIS site created on the remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check out [MsBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/Wikipage)? It has a task called [MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis6Website](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.5.0/index.html) wihch can be used to create a web site.

Disclaimer: I have never actually used that task with remote support, but the documentation claims is it supported :)

EDIT: you could also have a look at the WebDirectoryCreate task in the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) project.

Comment: I couldn't seem to find any documentation on MSBuild Extension Pack that shows remote setup. I got it working locally, but that doesn't seem to help. The same with Community Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) (which you can call from MSBuild). With MSDeploy you can install a Remote Agent Service which listens for actions to be executed on the target IIS server.